# How to retrieve Image from Web in JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx

This purpose of this code is to retrieve an Image from the web and then put in to a Image view in Java FX. I am getting a mismatch error of Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Buffered Image to Image. How can I retrieve the Image on from the web then display it on to my Application? What is this error mean for my Image, would this be a formatting issue?

My Code

```
  URL url2 = new URL("http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01004/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486615455EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG");
    
    Image image = ImageIO.read(url2);
    
    imageV.setImage(image);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t try to convert the image using swing and imageio. Also don’t create a URL object. None of that is necessary.

Just load the image directly from the url string using the [image constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)).

As noted in comments, you need to directly access the image on the server, not via a redirected location:

> if I change the protocol from http to https then it works. My guess is the website automatically upgrades to HTTPS, which I think results in a redirect, and I would not be surprised if JavaFX's image-loading implementation doesn't handle that.

Comment: Hello Thank you for the response, I tried Image image = new Image("http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01004/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486615455EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG");, however it still does not update the image?

Comment: That is not a valid url string, it needs a protocol to fetch stuff from the web, it also has extra characters on the end of the string so it does not locate an image.  You already have the correct string in your question, use that.

Comment: The URL I am using is http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/01004/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_486615455EDR_F0481570FHAZ00323M_.JPG, and for some reason it does not work, but when I use https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/640px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png it works, what could be the probelm?

Comment: @KhushThakor When I try to load your image I get `com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorageException: No loader for image data`. However, if I change the protocol from `http` to `https` then it works. My guess is the website automatically upgrades to HTTPS, which I think results in a redirect, and I would not be surprised if JavaFX's image-loading implementation doesn't handle that.